# Bash string comparison not working on function call

Tags: string, bash

Ok, I have the following complete bash code that I use to get the status of currently running linode using linode-cli:

```
#!/bin/bash

function linode_api() {
        hostname_fqdn="$1"
        linode_id=$(linode-cli linodes list --json --pretty | jq ".[] | select(.label == \"${hostname_fqdn}\") | .id")
        echo "Getting linode status for ${hostname_fqdn}..."
        linode_status=$(linode-cli linodes view "${linode_id}" --json --pretty | jq -r ".[] | .status")
        echo "${linode_status}"

}

linode_status=$(linode_api "server.domain.com")

echo "${linode_status}"
```

Now, if a linode called server.domain.com is running the output above is: running

The output doesn't have any double quotations or weird character.

But then, if add extra code for simple string comparison:

```
#!/bin/bash

function linode_api() {
        hostname_fqdn="$1"
        linode_id=$(linode-cli linodes list --json --pretty | jq ".[] | select(.label == \"${hostname_fqdn}\") | .id")
        echo "Getting linode status for ${hostname_fqdn}..."
        linode_status=$(linode-cli linodes view "${linode_id}" --json --pretty | jq -r ".[] | .status")
        echo "${linode_status}"

}

linode_status=$(linode_api "server.domain.com")

if [ "${linode_status}" == "running" ]; then

        echo "It's running"

else

        echo "It's not running"
fi
```

The output said:

It's not running

What could be the reason?

The expected output should be: It's running

EDIT:

Just now someone put an answer for this but deleted it. He said about multiple echo. So, I found out that the problem is because of the echo statement of this (if I delete this, it will work):

Code to remove:

```
echo "Getting linode status for ${hostname_fqdn}..."
```

but, since the output is one, why it didn't just compare and give the correct result.

So the variable $linode_status has the value of "running"

Why it didn't work if I have multiple echo statements ?

EDIT 2:

Include strace output before this line `linode_status=$(linode_api "server.domain.com")` with `set -x`

```
+++ linode_api server.domain.com
+++ hostname_fqdn=server.domain.com
++++ linode-cli linodes list --json --pretty
++++ jq '.[] | select(.label == "server.domain.com") | .id'
+++ linode_id=24805751
+++ echo 'Getting linode status for server.domain.com ...'
++++ linode-cli linodes view 24805751 --json --pretty
++++ jq -r '.[] | .status'
+++ linode_status=running
+++ echo running
++ echo -n 'Getting linode status for server.domain.com...
running'
+ linode_status='Getting linode status for server.domain.com...
running'
+ '[' 'Getting linode status for server.domain.com...
running' = running ']'
+ echo 'It'\''s not running'
It's not running
```

Comment: `[` is `test` (1). It uses `=`, not `==`.

Comment: Also you don't need `{...}` in "${linode_status}". Try to print this variable: are you sure that it really has a value "running" when your example fails?

Comment: btw, your `echo` in the function prints it with "\n". Try `echo -n ...`

Comment: Try checking the variable's value with `declare -p linode_status`, and I think the problem will be much clearer. Also, another useful technique that'll show the problem is to put `set -x` before the problem section, so it prints a trace of what's happening as it runs (very useful for debugging).

Comment: Yes, the output is running. Tried your suggestion, changing `linode_status=$(linode_api "server.domain.com")`
to  `linode_status=$(echo -n "$(linode_api "server.domain.com")")` doesn't work too

Comment: @GordonDavisson I included strace output in the question, doesn't seems to help much.

Comment: @RandomB How do I determine that the output produces the "\n" line?

Comment: it's the behaviour of the `echo`. So, either use `echo -n ...` or use `grep` instead of `=`. Also you can return numeral result instead of the string echo-ing

Comment: First if you use bash, then use `[[`, it's built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from @triplee given me a clue about the problem. I don't want to disturb any codes in the function (including removing any echo statements there). So, the only best solution I got is to change this assign function from:

```
linode_status=$(linode_api "server.domain.com")
```

into this:

```
linode_status=$(linode_api "server.domain.com" | tail -n 1)
```

This will take the last line of the output and ignore all other outputs

Answer (score 2):

The function returns multiple lines, so it can never be equal to a single line. The command substitution `$(linode_api)` expands to the output from the function, which includes output from every `echo` statement in the function (unless you separately redirect them).

Probably remove the status `echo` completely, or if you really insist on keeping it, send it to standard error; that's why we have a separate output channel for status messages.

Actually probably remove the final [useless `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo), too.

```sh
linode_api() {
        hostname_fqdn="$1"
        linode_id=$(linode-cli linodes list --json --pretty | jq ".[] | select(.label == \"${hostname_fqdn}\") | .id")
        # Notice redirect; probably remove altogether
        echo "Getting linode status for ${hostname_fqdn}..." >&2
       linode-cli linodes view "${linode_id}" --json --pretty | jq -r ".[] | .status"
}
```

Comment: I just updated my question, did you refer this to the current question ?

Comment: Your edit removed the problem, so I deleted my answer. Please make sure your question is a proper [mre].

Comment: No, I found out that having echo at the end is not a problem. The solutions is just to remove this line `echo "Getting linode status for ${hostname_fqdn}..."`. The last one doesn't need to be removed.

Comment: It doesn't *need* to be removed, no; it just needlessly complicates your code and reveals that you didn't read the link I included.

Comment: No, your answer doesn't work. This is because linode-cli command already output another echo (as it has its own echo statement). The only solution I got right now is to use tail -n 1 (I just found out)

Comment: Since I didn't know what was the problem, I couldn't narrow down the code. But, now I understand after you have given me a clue "about the multiple echos statement before" It's simply not related to the API

Comment: Your `strace` suggests otherwise; but if you managed to solve your probdem, good.

Comment: thanks, I just notice your standard error answer. Putting redirect to standard error works but that function is also needed by other program to have standard output.

Comment: Yes, bash is not python which can return explicit value. The problem is multiple echos. See https://gist.github.com/jirib/03bec20348aa730606a7088a797b2a21

Comment: It's hard to see how a diagnostic output which merely repeats its input would be generally useful, though it might help for debugging. Maybe change the function to accept a second parameter to make it verbose (or turn off verbosity if you have many callers which require verbose output, or callers you can't easily change to use the more natural convention) and/or set up a global debug flag.

Comment: @MaXi32 A big advantage of creating a minimal reproducible example -- especially via the "divide and conquer" method -- is that it lets you *find out* where the problem is. When you remove everything that isn't needed to demo the problem, the source of the problem becomes much easier to identify and understand.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I agree with you on this. Actually this code that I wrote here is part of the more than 10 thousand line of source codes. So, I think I had done my best taking out some of the code and made it a complete working code (just that you need linode-cli and jq installed). The reason I didn't remove the linode-cli and jq before becauseI thought it might be the problem was came from the API or quering issue. If I would have thought it was the echo problem, the code would be simpler than this but I don't think the current code in the question is complex with just few lines of code